# enabling bookmarking while using jQuery .load();

Tags: jquery, load, bookmarks

I have a file name "project_profiles.html" which looks like this:

```
<div id="project1">
    <p>Project 1</p>
</div>

<div id="project2">
    <p>Project 2</p>
</div>

<div id="project3">
    <p>Project 3</p>
</div>
```

On my index page, I use this: $('#content').load(project_profiles.html #project1');

Then, the index page loads showing only the div with the id project 1.  That's fine however, if the user tries to bookmark the page it won't work.  Is there a way to make the bookmarking work while having all of the project div's in one file??

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content').load(project_profiles.html #project1');
location.hash = "#project1";
```

Then they should be able to bookmark it.  The next step is auto loading the correct content based on the location.hash if present on page load.

#### Edit

in your js (preferable in the $(document).ready function) place the following code

```
if(location.hash)
$('#content').load('/_catalogs/html/project_details.htm ' + location.hash);
```

and if you can without breaking anything change

```
<a href="#p1" onclick="$('#content').load('/_catalogs/html/project_details.htm #project1');">Read More</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#project1" onclick="$('#content').load('/_catalogs/html/project_details.htm #project1');">Read More</a>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. This is actual code I'm using: <a href="#p1" onclick="$('#content').load('/_catalogs/html/project_details.htm #project1');">Read More</a>  This places a #p1 hash tag in the URL when It loads the information, but the bookmarking doesn't work.

Comment: ah! then it's the page onload that isn't coded... sec let me edit my answer.

Comment: GENIUS!!! Thank you!  I knew the answer was simple, I just don't know javaScript well enough.  The entire thing should be put in a function rather than placing onclick's everywhere but one thing at a time ;) hahaha

Comment: Actually...one question, since you are so smart ;), when I click on the links, the page flashes and almost looks like the page is reloading even though it isn't.  Do you know how to avoid the "flashing" and have it load smoother?

Comment: @Dana Could be several factors causing that.  One way to do prevent this is to set any content wrappers to `display:none` in the css and then perform `$("myContent").show();` after you're sure the content is fully loaded.  Without a demo site to see this happening on, however, it's somewhat difficult to know what will really work. If you have one (or better yet some kind of http://jsfiddle.net) I can take a look.